# Hover image link clicking through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my hover image in mobile devices. The hover image hides a href link with opacity set to 0 and on hover the link appears on the image. All very logical in a computer where you use mouse. But in mobile devices when you tap the right place, where the link is hidden, it simply jumps through the first hover state and right to the link. The link is hidden from sight but is still clickable. Is it possible to somehow make the link appear on tap (you tap he picture, it does some animation and link appears) and then when the link is visible you can click it? I have tried some solutions I found but none of them have worked.

Here is my CSS:

```
.img-responsive{
    width:100%;
    height:auto%;
}
.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: translateX(0);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
.hovereffect:hover img {
    filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" /></filter></svg>#filter');
    filter: grayscale(1) blur(3px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-filter: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:  translateX(0);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.hovereffect a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hovereffect a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
.hovereffect a.info, .hovereffect h2 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:  translateX(0);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transition: translateX(0);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hovereffect:hover a.info, .hovereffect:hover h2 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:  translateX(0);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="toad" class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="picture1.gif" alt="some text">
            <div class="overlay">
               <h2>some other text</h2>
               <a id="link1" class="info" href="#myLINK">href link1 text</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="block">
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="picture2.gif" alt="text">
            <div class="overlay">
               <h2>other text</h2>
               <a id="link2" class="info" href="#myLINK2">href link2 text</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with this problem. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Instead of setting the opacity to 0 can you just set display:none which will hide the element. so you can toggle display:inline-block and display:none

Comment: I tried it and it isn't working. It is still "clicking" the href when not visible.

Comment: Can you recreate this in jsfiddle or provide a link to the live page?

Comment: Are you willing to use Javascript?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f70sa2bx/2/ here you go. Tested it on my mobile and the same problem occurs. I don't mind using javascript. Right now my javascript "solution" is that the href requires a double-tap in mobile devices, so the first accidental click to the right place on the image won't trigger the link... but it's really inconvenient to require the users to double tap something (in most cases, they just give up after the first tap and assume the link is broken).